# SSH Two-Factor auth (2FA) with a yubikey

Tags: ssh, two-factor, yubikey

I have got this slick little yubikey and I want to add an additional layer of security when authenticating ssh sessions. On the server side I've already disabled password authentication and only permit the use of ssh keys when logging in.

The problem is, after configuring sshd and PAM for yubikey auth, sshd still only requires an ssh key, I'm never asked to provide a response from the yubikey.

How do I require *both* and ssh key *and* a yubikey?

`(ubuntu 14.04 - trusty)`

`/etc/pam.d/common-auth`:

```
auth    required    pam_yubico.so mode=client try_first_pass id=<id> key=<secret>
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional            pam_cap.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
...

PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
UsePAM yes
```

Comment: BTW, if you don't get a satisfactory answer in a couple days, ping me and I'll put a healthy bounty on the question. I have rep to burn, and I'm interested in this answer as well. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I kept at it and I think I've come up with a reasonable solution. The primary thing I was previously missing was sshd's `AuthenticationMethods publickey,password`. This enforces the requirement for both a publickey *and* a password -- "password"s now being handled by `PAM->auth-yubi`. Additional changes were also needed, see below:

*(ubuntu 14.04 - trusty):*

#### /etc/pam.d/yubi-auth

```
auth    required pam_yubico.so mode=client try_first_pass id=<id> key=<key>
```

*Note: you can obtain your access ID and secret key [here](https://upgrade.yubico.com/getapikey/)*

#### /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
# Standard Un*x authentication.
#@include common-auth

# Yubikey auth
@include yubi-auth
```

#### /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
UsePAM yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

`service ssh restart`

### Verification

#### SSH from a remote host *without* a public key

```
root@0a6442bcb21c:/# ssh ben@192.168.1.20
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.20 (192.168.1.20)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is ea:2a:e3:98:35:72:66:b1:e0:65:6b:3f:60:8a:af:ab.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.20' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

#### SSH from a remote host *with* a public key

```
$ ssh ben@192.168.1.20
Authenticated with partial success.
ben@192.168.1.20's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-33-generic x86_64)
```

### Improvement

It would be nice to see "Yubikey Auth:" instead of "password:" from the remote ssh server when authenticating.

What happens when the ssh server is unable to contact yubico's auth verification system? An ideal solution would be entirely self-contained.

Comments and suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up 2FA with Yubikey can be tricky (thought there is openssh [patch for U2F](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2319)), but the easiest way is probably the one described on [Yubico official website](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-piv-tool/SSH_with_PIV_and_PKCS11.html).

It is basically the way of storing your private key on the Yubikey and protecting it with PIN. It is not exactly the 2FA you are described (but it is something what you *have* and and what you *know*), but it increases the security even more (Yubikey locks after some unsuccessful tries).

## TL:DR;

```
OPENSC_LIBS=`locate opensc-pkcs11.so`
yubico-piv-tool -s 9a -a generate -o public.pem
yubico-piv-tool -a verify-pin -P 123456 -a selfsign-certificate -s 9a \
  -S "/CN=SSH key/" -i public.pem -o cert.pem
yubico-piv-tool -a import-certificate -s 9a -i cert.pem
ssh-keygen -D $OPENSC_LIBS/opensc-pkcs11.so -e
ssh -I $OPENSC_LIBS/opensc-pkcs11.so user@remote.example.com
```

Comment: "*I believe the pam module is able to authenticate only local Yubikeys, not the ones over ssh*" - I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that.  Do you mean that a Yubikey can't be used to authenticate to a remote ssh server via PAM?

Comment: Yes. Because it needs the way to communicate with the yubikey and it is probably done using some local library. There is no code for this in ssh.

Comment: That is definitely wrong.  I have configured my remote servers to accept yubikey-based authentication in both [native yubikey mode](http://www.teaparty.net/technotes/yubikey.html) and [OATH mode](http://www.teaparty.net/technotes/yubikey-oath.html).  The whole point of a yubikey is a to provide a short(ish) string to transmit over a potentially-insecure channel, to act as a one-time password.  If the yubikey had to be physically attached to the system it was authenticating to, it would be a lot less useful.  I *think* you're wrong about the yubikey locking in PKCS mode, as well.

Comment: OK, you are right. For OTP mode it is possible. But the locking is part of PKCS11 standard.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the last comment. The yubikey locks itself, not the server.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the circumstances under which you think the yubikey locks itself?

Comment: When server requests signing the challenge, ssh asks the PKCS library to sign the challenge using the key stored on the yubikey. The key is PIN protected, so the user is prompted to enter the PIN. If he enters wrong one, three times or so, the yubikey locks for signing and requires PUK as described in the [documentation](https://developers.yubico.com/yubico-piv-tool/YubiKey_PIV_introduction.html).

Comment: Thank you for that - I feel your answer is much better for the improvements, and will remove my downvote.